# Get the href value of a previous HTML anchoer, <a>, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the value of href of <a> that is the previous element to my current button that is clicked. How do I get it?

Here is my code.

#### HTML:

```
<a href="#activityNotes[0].noteText">
    <input value="Add Another" name="addAnotherNote" type="submit" class="addAnother secondary" onclick="addAnotherNote();"/>
</a>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(".addAnother").click(function() {
    var jump = $(this).prev("a").attr("href");
});
```

When I try running this, I get

> jump value undefined.

Why is this happening? Is it because I'm trying to get an anchor with `#` in front?

http://jsfiddle.net/5Twfc/2/

Actually I am trying to get the display to anchor section with `name/id = activityNotes[0].noteText` when I click on the add button. That is the reason I have this input button inside the <a>. Also, I am doing a form submit after I run few scripts.

```
$(".addAnother").click(function() {
    var jump = $(this).parent().attr("href");
    var new_position = $('#'+jump).offset();
    window.scrollTo(new_position.left,new_position.top);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Why dont you try to create a teporary element or variable to handle the href value of the previous element,

Comment: It seems odd to have an input field inside the link. Don't know if this is even valid.

Comment: I fail to see the purpose of wrapping a submit button inside an anchor element.   Surely, there's a better way.   And with jQuery the inline onclick is made  totally obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` encloses `input`. `prev` gets previous sibling. In this case, you need to get the parent. Here's what will work based on your jsFiddle:

```
$(".addAnother").click(function() {
    var jump = $(this).parent().attr('href');
    $('#printJumpValue').text('' + jump);
})
```

and a live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/5Twfc/4/

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of href try to use this

```
    $('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because this points to the input. To get the anchor either move the class to it or use the following:

```
$(this).parent().prev("a").attr("href")
```

Comment: Based on the jsfiddle, I think he wants the anchor which is wrapped directly around the button itself, making the ".prev" function unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The prev function gets the previous *sibling*.  You want the parent item:

```
$(this).parent().attr("href");
```