# how to get the href of a link when i press another href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i want to get the attr href of an above link beside the one i press wich is the last link from `productinfo` div class. I tryed with closest but it gets me the same link i press and i want the above one. The link i want to store in `produs_href` is the link from first `href` under `productinfo` class. Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 produse"><!--PRODUS-->
    <div class="product-image-wrapper">
        <div class="single-products">
            <div class="productinfo text-center">
                <a href="/'.$recomand['ID_Produs'].'/'.$recomand['Nume_Prod'].'.php"><img src="/images/produse/'.$recomand['ID_Produs'].'/'.$recomand['Poza'].'" alt="" /></a>
                <h2 style="text-decoration: line-through;">'.$recomand['Pret'].' lei </h2><h2>'.$recomand['Pret_Nou'].' lei </h2>
                <a href="link produs"><p>'.$recomand['Nume_Prod'].' '.$recomand['Gramaj'].' '.$tip.'</p></a>
                <a href="/engine/app/cos.php?id='.$recomand['ID_Produs'].'" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart cos"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Adaugă în coș</a>
            </div>          
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
    $(".cos").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var produs_href = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
    $.getJSON(href, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $("#cnt").empty();
             $("#test").append('<li>' + val.nume + '</li>')
             $("#cnt").append('' + val.cnt +'')
        });
    });
    $(\'#detalii_prod\').modal('show'); 
    alert(produs_href);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: based on your comment on other answer, I posted my answer. Try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/). This method gets the immediately preceding sibling.

```
$(this).prev().attr('href');
```

**EDIT**

From your comments, the code that would do the trick is

```
$(this).closest('.productinfo').find('a:first').attr('href');
```

Comment: prev works but it goes only 1 position back, i need 2 positions since the link i want is 2 positions back

Comment: @chris227: so far I see on the html you show, that's not true :). Link containing `link produs` is the inmediatly previous sibling

Comment: maybe i didn't express well, the link i want to get is first under `productinfo` div class wich is `href="/'.$recomand['ID_Produs'].'/'.$recomand['Nume_Prod'].'.php"`

Comment: @chris227: I misunderstood your question. Fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .prev

var link = $(this).prev().attr('href');

and now you can use link.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this 
$(this).prev("a").attr("href");

and more help:
[Get the href value of a previous HTML anchoer, <a>, using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779833/get-the-href-value-of-a-previous-html-anchoer-a-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".cos").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

  var text = $(this).parent().find('a:first').attr('href');
  alert(text);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 produse">
  <!--PRODUS-->
  <div class="product-image-wrapper">
    <div class="single-products">
      <div class="productinfo text-center"> <a href="test.php"><img src="img/Penguins.jpg" height="50" width="50" alt="" /></a>
        <h2 style="text-decoration: line-through;">Hello there</h2>
        <h2>Anto</h2>
        <a href="link produs">
        <p>Angeline</p>
        </a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart cos"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Test</a> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

try this

```
$(this).parent().find('a:first').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.eq()` method.

```
$(this).parent().find('a').eq(0).attr('href');
```

Hope this helps you...